# Java REST jersey produces URL

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I have a method that return java.net.URL and I can´t find the right MediaType for the @Produces annotation. Is possible to produce an URL MediaType?

My code:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML) //MediaType I don´t know
@Path("terms.html")
public URL getTerms(){

    Iterator<String> it=definitions.keySet().iterator();
    URL url,url1=null;
    try {
        url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/Dictionary/definitions/");
        url1 = new URL(url,it.next()+".html");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return url1;
}
```

What I want in my rest service is something like that:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no [content type](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/4_Content-Type.html) for URLs.

You can assume the URL you are returning is a piece of plain text and use [`MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/MediaType.html#TEXT_PLAIN):

```
@GET
@Path("terms.html")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public URL getTerms() {
    ...
}
```

---

If you need, you can return a HTML document (using [`MediaType.TEXT_HTML`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/MediaType.html#TEXT_HTML)) containing an [`<a>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a), referencing the URL you want to return.

Answer (score 1):

The media type is meant to denote what sort of document is being returned. And while there are "HTML documents" and "XML documents" and "Microsoft word documents" - each of which has a MIME type you could use - there isn't any such thing as a "URL document". So, it makes sense not to have a corresponding media type. If you are literally just returning the URL with no HTML/JSON/XML/whatever, then I'd use text.